# will it help to find the optimal solution to set cover problem if all exact-covers of the same problem were found

Tags: set-cover

I have a set cover problem in the real world, it is a unicost set cover problem, with many subsets(around 10~30 million subsets, yes, no mistake here). Due to the nature of the problem in real world, it is kind of easy to find all the exact covers of the problem. I am trying very hard to find a better set-cover solution in many ways, but no luck. With all exact covers of the problem are found, could it be easier to find the optimal solution of the set cover problem? Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: The unicost set covering problem is an actively researched area of cs. So your best bet is probably going through recent papers and seeing what applies to your specific problem. The GRASP algorithm might be a start. It uses a known solution and then tries to improve on that solution, so you could enter one of the exact cover solutions and let the GRASP algorithm improve it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will look into it. But my question is will exact overs help to find the optimal for paticular unicost set cover problem in p time?

Comment: Small question: is every subset implicated in some exact cover?

Comment: Q:is every subset implicated in some exact cover? yes, every subset is in one and only exact cover. here is something already known, every subset  has a upper limit of its length (for a reduced run it is 81), and every element are in a certain number of subsets(for a reduced run, evey element is in 330 different subsets exactly). and it has 330 different exact covers.

Comment: Since all exact covers are found, does it mean all feasiable solution are known for Ax=1?